# Angular UI Calendar Issue

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ui-calendar

I've used Ionic-3 for my university project, I have some issue, I  want to know how to install this calendar http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/ correctly in Ionic project?
I tried it, it does not work please help me fix this?

Comment: Go to its github link, all information is there

Comment: @MustafaLokhandwala Sir , i try it and install  `bower install --save angular-ui-calendar` but not work

Comment: then is it mandatory to use this calender?

Comment: Sir I want to add my project for dynamically some event , Im try to find some calendar ,But not for ionic, sir I was try this but cant added this to event https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47747672/ion2-calendar-event-issue

Comment: Okk I got it what you want

Comment: Correctly I want to  know how to added this http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/ calendar for my project :( I m try to 2hours

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160925/discussion-between-core114-and-mustafa-lokhandwala).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-fullcalendar** for your custom events.

Comment: Thanks Madam, Your first solution is work for me :D now I  can customize